# in sql (oracle) how can I select something that has a alower case letter and an "whatever" case letter

Tags: sql, oracle, uppercase, lowercase

I mean if I have a column of names like

Angora Bunny

Christian Scott

aNNe White

etc

etc

and I'd like to select every name that has "An" or "an" in it.

so I'll get both **An**gora and Christi**an** as a result, but not **aN**Ne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this as an example:

```
select * from table_x where (column1 like '%An%' or column1 like '%an%') and column1 not like '%aN%';
```

Comment: The only solution to this not LIke/OR, but converting everything to Lower or Upper case on both sides e.g. SELECT value FROM table WHERE lover(value)  = lover(searched_value).

Answer (score 0):

---Try this

WITH TESTDATE AS

(
 SELECT 'Angora Bunny' NAMES FROM DUAL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Christian Scott' FROM DUAL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'aNNe White' FROM DUAL

UNION ALL

SELECT 'aNNeAn' FROM dual

)

SELECT * FROM TESTDATE WHERE REGEXP_INSTR( NAMES ,'An|an') > 0